# My android app doesn't work on phone and does work on emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, emulation

I made app and it successfully works on my android studio emulator. 
But it stops on my phone (not only on mine, also on another phone) with message "app stops unexpectedly". So I tried installing blank app with basic activity, it failed also. Please help me ToT

```
30887-30887/com.pbs.medicationmanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.pbs.medicationmanager, PID: 30887
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pbs.medicationmanager/com.pbs.medicationmanager.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat.
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5116)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat.
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:692)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
       at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:83)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:193)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:173)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:511)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
       at com.pbs.medicationmanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5116) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: check whether your phone is already in developer mode

Answer (score 1):

update your **Gradle**

```
buildscript {
  ...
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
  }
}
```